# xcode executable can't access .txt file that's a part of the project

Tags: xcode, file

I've created an Xcode console application that uses a .txt file within the project to populate a dictionary (it's a map - but that's besides the point).

This program runs fine when I run the project through Xcode, and populates the dictionary with the contents of the file correctly. I use a relative path inside of the program, based on the file's location in the project folder.

When I create the executable, and access it separately from Xcode in terminal, it does not find the file (program runs without issue - just doesn't have a dictionary).

I believe this has to do with the Build Phases setup in Xcode, because it isn't copying over the .txt file when it builds the executable, but I'm having trouble finding sufficient documentation to make this work correctly.

Can one of you kind souls please point me in the right direction? I've been searching for hours.  I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Writing out the full path name in Xcode when accessing the file resulted in the executable being created with the file information in it. This solved the probem.

**More information/thoughts:**

This is counter-intuitive to me, as I had imagined that Xcode would include the file without needing the full path in code, since it was able to find the file with relative path when running the program through Xcode, to begin with.

To restate:

- Xcode runs the program without issue when running internally, through Xcode, regardless of how the file path is specified.
- The executable will only work with the file when I change the .cpp code to list the file as a full path.

I have a feeling that this is a sloppy way to resolve the file inclusion into the executable (it broadcasts my directories on my home computer, for anyone reading the code on GitHub).

I will not be marking this as an accepted answer for now, as I am hoping that someone else will be able to figure out a smarter way around this by the time I finish my little project.

Answer (score 0):

To copy files when you build, run, and archive your project *uncheck* `Copy only when installing`.

For your use case I'd suggest Copy Files to Products Directory and add your text file.

Documentation is hard to find, so here are some tips:

1. Build Settings

   - Xcode's build settings panel have environment counterparts, but they don't mirror them.

     - For example, the build setting `Installation Directory` is the counterpart to the environment variable `INSTALL_PATH`.
   - Hover over the build setting **value** for a tool-tip describing it's environment variable, if any.
   - Run the command `xcodebuild -showBuildSettings` at the root of your project folder.
2. Copy Files Destinations

   - *Absolute Path* is an actual absolute path. If `Copy only` ... is unchecked it will copy the files to the path specified.

     - However, it will **fail silently** for certain paths. For example `~/Desktop` will fail, but `~/Desktop/subdir` will not.
     - Use absolute path to install data to known directory such as `~/.local/share` or `/usr/local/share` or `~/Library/Application Support/YourApp`.
   - *Products Directory* is where your binary will be placed.

     - It is equal to `BUILD_DIR` or `TARGET_BUILD_DIR` or `INSTALL_DIR`.
   - Most of the other destinations will expand to products directory for command line tool target.
3. See the install structure of your app by creating an Archive. Go to Product > Archive. Then in the Archive popup select Distribute Content > Built Products.

Hope this helps.